# Crash resilience of InnoDb vs. MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

We run a MySQL server on Windows. Sometimes, Windows crashes, and leaves the database in a corrupt state ("Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'" messages though the key is auto-generated; that can be repaired with a "Repair table" command).

I have seen that problem with MyISAM tables only, never with an InnoDb table. Did that happen by chance, or is InnoDb with its extra code for transactions actually more resilient towards such failures?

Comment: *"Did that happen by chance, or is InnoDb with its extra code for transactions actually more resilient towards such failures?"* Yes that is the case, innoDB is much more resilient  then MyISAM..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyISAM does not support any of the four qualities of [ACID databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

InnoDB is designed for crash recovery. It has several features that prevent such corruption in the case of crashes, and also recover from crashes automatically, so you don't have to run REPAIR TABLE.

InnoDB has been the default storage engine since [MySQL 5.5.5 in 2010](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-5.html). It's clear that MySQL is moving (slowly) in the direction of phasing out MyISAM. In MySQL 8.0, even the system tables in the `mysql` schema have been converted to InnoDB.

It's really time to just consider MyISAM obsolete technology and stop using it. We should honor its place in history, but move on to a better solution.

Comment: *"It's really time to just consider MyISAM obsolete technology and stop using it. We should honor its place in history, but move on to a better solution."* Well for [Internal disk based temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) for query processing if needed i rather have MyISAM storage engine .. i still need to do some benchmarking on this point on MySQL 8 but i have a feeling MyISAM is (much) faster there i could be wrong as i believe MySQL 8.0 has new storage engine. (something like TempTable i believe)

Comment: "[Beginning with MySQL 8.0.16, the storage engine used for on-disk internal temporary tables is always InnoDB.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html)" The TempTable storage engine may be used only for in-memory temp tables, and the alternative is the MEMORY storage engine. It seems that MyISAM is no longer an option for temp tables.

Comment: indeed thanks i didn't really looked at it before but *"
In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported.
"* [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine) so it pretty much removes benchmarking options...

Comment: Agreed Bill!  The one time I've purposely used MyISAM recently is for a logging table where I wanted entries to persist even after a rollback.  The non-transactional behavior was desirable.